How to fix "paths[0]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array" error when introducing Mustache partials with ExpressJS?
index.js logging the view paths to ensure partials are visable
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import mustacheExpress from 'mustache-express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import homeRouter from './home/router.js';
import jobsRouter from './jobs/router.js';
import errors from './errors/errors.js';

dotenv.config();

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

// Configure mustache
app.set('views', [
  path.join(__dirname, 'home'), // Home templates
  path.join(__dirname, 'jobs'), // Jobs templates
  path.join(__dirname, 'errors'), // Error templates
  path.join(__dirname, 'site/partial-views'),
]);
console.log('Views set to:', app.get('views'));

app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
app.engine('mustache', mustacheExpress());

// Routes
app.use('/', homeRouter);
app.use('/jobs', jobsRouter);

// Error handling middleware
app.use(errors.notFound);
app.use(errors.internalServerError);
app.use(errors.emailError);

export default app;


terminal with views log
[nodemon] starting `node ./app/server.js`
Views set to: [
  'C:\\Users\\Keegan\\source\\repos\\my-website\\app\\home',
  'C:\\Users\\Keegan\\source\\repos\\my-website\\app\\jobs',
  'C:\\Users\\Keegan\\source\\repos\\my-website\\app\\errors',
  'C:\\Users\\Keegan\\source\\repos\\my-website\\app\\site\\partial-views'
]
Server running on port 3000
Connected to MySQL database

terminal with error
node:internal/errors:540
      throw error;
      ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[0]" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array
    at Object.resolve (node:path:198:9)
    at C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\mustache-express\mustache-express.js:99:24
    at C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:247:13
    at eachOfArrayLike (C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:507:13)
    at eachOf (C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:627:16)
    at awaitable (C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:212:32)
    at _asyncMap (C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:245:16)
    at Object.map (C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:750:16)
    at Object.awaitable [as map] (C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:212:32)
    at loadAllPartials (C:\Users\Keegan\source\repos\my-website\node_modules\mustache-express\mustache-express.js:94:8) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v22.12.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

directory
my-website/
----app/
--------index.js
--------server.js
--------db.js
--------config.js
--------jobs/router.js, jobs.mustache
--------home/router.js, home.mustache
--------errors/errors.js, erorrs.mustache
--------site/partial-views/head.mustache
----public/

home.mustache
<html lang="en" data-bs-theme="auto">
{{> head}}
</html>

home/router.js
import express from 'express';
import connection from '../db.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const query = 'SELECT id, title, location, salary, posted FROM jobs';

  connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.render('home', { jobs: results });
  });
});

export default router;


home.mustache is currently the only template attempting to use the partial. Removing the 1 line {{> head}} in home.mustache and manually copying the contents of head.mustache in its place removes the error, and  thewebsite renders the '/' root endpoint correctly.
Thank you for your time and feedback !

I found a solution but it doesn't fully solve the problem as to why the question code isn't accepted. Current solution I have is adding the partial-views path directly into the mustache express constructor like so.
const mustache = mustacheExpress(path.join(__dirname, 'site', 'partial-views')); 
app.engine('mustache', mustache);

This ensures express knows about this directory.
You can then remove
path.join(__dirname, 'site/partial-views'),
app.set('views', [
  path.join(__dirname, 'home'), // Home templates
  path.join(__dirname, 'jobs'), // Jobs templates
  path.join(__dirname, 'errors'), // Error templates


  path.join(__dirname, 'site/partial-views'),


]);

This works but there is still confusion on exactly why the oringinal code doesn't and unsure if this is the graceful / intended solution or not .
